# Hide footer and footer message after particular interval using $timeout()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, intel-xdk

I am trying to create an angular app using Intel `XDK`. Here when I run the index page we can see footer message. What I need is the footer and footer message will  hide after 5 seconds using timeout().

But my code of below is not working.

**index.html**

```
 <div class="bar bar-footer bar-balanced" style="background-color:#444444;">
            <div class="title">{{footer_message}}</div>
        </div>
```

**app.js**

```
     app.controller('main', function ($scope,$interval,$timeout,$ionicModal,localStorageService,$http,$q,$templateCache) {
        $scope.footer_message ='Powered By';

        $scope.checkConnection=function() {
                    var networkState = navigator.connection.type;

                    if(networkState == Connection.NONE){
                        $scope.footer_message = "No Network Connection";

                        return false;

                    }
                    else{
                        $scope.footer_message = "Powered by";
                        return true;
                    }
                }


        $scope.showFooter=function(){
                $timeout(function () {
                    $scope.footer_message = null;
            }, 5000);
           }
        $scope.showFooter();
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nisr19/zz2cn106/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I have created one example for you check this plunkr
http://plnkr.co/edit/PLTgJ2JraNOHAwNKk7iY?p=preview
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you give your footer an Id and then do `("#footerId").hide()` in the timeout

Also hope you added the `$timeout` dependency in your controller

Answer (score 0):

Correct it as below,

```
<div class="bar bar-footer bar-balanced" ng-if="footer_message != 'null'" style="background-color:#444444;">
            <div class="title">{{footer_message}}</div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything fine with your code...
I tried $timeout in fiddle
[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nisr19/zz2cn106/1/)

```
angular.module('ExampleApp', [])
    .controller('DemoController', function ($scope, $http, $q,$timeout) {

       $timeout(function(){
       $scope.footer_message=null;
       },5000);

    });
```

Edited1:
[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nisr19/zz2cn106/2/)

this is work for check internet connection

```
 if(navigator.onLine){
          $scope.footer_message='success';
          }
          else{
          $scope.footer_message=' no network ';
          }
```

Comment: Your code is fine.But I have 2 footer messages like if there is no internet footer message will be no network or there is footer message like success @nisar

Comment: your code is fine and its working successfully.but here I want to hide not only footer message footer  too

Comment: then hide the fotter div inside the timeout function @sherinks

Comment: how to hide footer div in $timeout() ? @nisar

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nisr19/zz2cn106/3/    documnet.getElementById('fotter').style.display='none';

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **ng-hide** for your footer div

```
<div ng-hide="footer_message==null" class="bar bar-footer bar-balanced" style="background-color:#444444;">
   <div class="title">{{footer_message}}</div>
</div>
```